# New Semester publicity contest

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

With the semester starting around now for most universities, this site is now relevant to a whole bunch of new first-year grad students. We should try to capitalize on that by some targeted marketing, mainly consisting of flyers targeted at first-year graduate students. I can try to put something together, but I was wondering whether anyone else either (1) wants to make their own, or (2) has any other good ideas for publicity.

Some of the other SE sites run occasional contests; that may work for us, but I haven't been able to think of what the contest would be about. Anyone have ideas about that? Note that we could advertise the contest on said flyers, which may make more folks want to visit.

Some examples of previous contests on other SE sites:

- [SuperUser.SE anniversary contest](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/super-user-1-year-anniversary-super-contest/)
- [Security.SE anniversary contest](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/887/official-security-stack-exchange-anniversary-competition)
- [An interesting English.SE  limerick contest, outside of SE but SE-sponsored](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1921/check-out-this-limerick-contest-were-sponsoring)

Comment: Do you have examples of the other contests you mention? That could be helpful to get inspiration :)

Comment: @charles - Done.